# iOS background task

Tags: ios, background-task

I have a simple application connected to a server, that should download from it some data regularly. Basically, the server stores a number which increases over time; the user has a certain number and could ask to be notified as soon as the server gets close to his number.

Therefore, when the user requests to be notified, a service should start and get info (every approx 40 seconds) about the current number. When user and server numbers are close enough, a local notification should be displayed.

I had no problems in implementing this in Android (AlarmManager + Background Service), but I can't in iOS. I read that for long running background tasks in iOS my app should be a music app, a voip app, a newspaper app, etc.. but mine is none of those. All I can do is run a background task when the app enters background, but it lasts no more that 2 minutes before the app gets killed.

Comment: Polling like this is inefficient in terms of energy and network use. Your server should send a push notification when the conditions are met.